# 302 redirect issues. Page header shows 302 for all pages

Tags: redirect, 301-redirect

If I use an online redirect checker like [redirect-checker](http://www.redirect-checker.org/) or [seobook.com](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/)
I do get a "SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily" for all pages, even for the homepage.

I tried to fix it by modifying .htaccess:

```
#RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [R=301,L]
```

But this results in a "broken" redirect like:

```
http://www.example.com/www/sites/www.example.com/files/html/index.php
```

Further I changed

> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options

and set "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to 301 (before 302). Cleared ALL caches in backend and var/cache - The online checker still show the same - 302.

Any ideas how to fix the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it - in my case a GEO Location extension was responsible for the issue.

Anyway - to check in general I recommend to take a look in

- .htaccess
- index.php
- search for keywords like
  "controller_action_predispatch" events, "header('Location:" or
  ""HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" to identify related extensions and disable
  these.

Comment: thanks its work for me , issue was geo location

Comment: how did you resolve the issue in geolocations extension?